# Is "for almost each object" good grammar in this example?

Tags: grammar, mathematics

In the 2nd paragraph at [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), these is the following sentence.

"In particular, **for almost each object** it is not possible to compute even a lower bound for its Kolmogorov complexity ..."

This phrasing  **for almost each object** looks off to me.  But am I missing something, that would make this good English grammar, in the context where it is used?

Answer (score 2):

This sounded better to me by shifting the statement after the comma : -

Original :

> In particular, for almost each object it is not possible to compute even a lower bound for its Kolmogorov complexity (Chaitin 1964), let alone its exact value.

Changed:

> In particular, it is not possible for almost **every** object to compute even a lower bound for its Kolmogorov complexity (Chaitin 1964), let alone its exact value.

Reason :

> In particular, it is not possible for (*removed almost here*) **every** object to compute even a lower bound for its Kolmogorov complexity (Chaitin 1964), let alone its exact value.

sounds correct. Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Hi @K-devlife10, thanks for the suggestions.  I wanted a math domain opinion  because of the specialist topic. See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652963/does-for-almost-each-object-make-sense-in-this-example/2652973#2652973  Based on that feedback I edited the original, can you see my revision on Wikipedia?

Comment: Hello @MikeRoger, thanks for the feedback. yes i can see the edit : In particular, for almost **all** objects, it is not possible to compute even a lower bound for its Kolmogorov complexity (Chaitin 1964), let alone its exact value.
Your edit is sounding more correct than 'every'.

If my response satisfied you, can you please Tick-mark this as the Answer? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @K-devlife10. I guess if nobody quibbles with the edit, the correction will stand.  FYI, a quick Google showed the suspect wording copied literatim elsewhere.  I do not think I will go chasing those.